# How do I update the content of a field type in the onAfterElementSave() method?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

I am building a field type for Craft that needs to do additional processing to the saved data once the element id is available. For this reason, the `prepValueFromPost()` method won't work, since the element id isn't available yet.

So how to update the content of the current element from the `onAfterElementSave()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return the content for the specific element instance you're on:

```
$this->element->getContent()
```

And from there you can do your additional content processing.

When you're ready so save it, you can call:

```
craft()->content->saveContent($this->element);
```

There are several examples in `craft/app/fieldtypes` folder where Craft's native field types do additional processing like this.

Comment: So if I update a property on the `ContentModel`, how does that data get saved to the db? When I update my property, the new data isn't saved to the db and you can't call `save()` on models.

Comment: I figured it out. I just ran the following code to save the content. `craft()->content->saveContent($this->element);` If there is a better way, let me know. If not, may be helpful to update your answer with that code and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: That's the way... updated!